# How to include and access data files in Python distribution?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to create a distributable Python package. For that, I organized my directories as follows:

```
.
├── config
│   └── test.yml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── sample
│   ├── hello.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── world
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── refer.py
└── setup.py
```

The `MANIFEST.in` contains only one line:

```
graft config
```

The `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='sample',
    version='1.0',
    packages=[
        'sample',
        'sample.world'
    ],
    include_package_data=True
)
```

However, after I have run `pip install .`, I end up with the following content of the target directory:

```
.
./__pycache__
./__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
./__pycache__/hello.cpython-36.pyc
./world
./world/__pycache__
./world/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
./world/__pycache__/refer.cpython-36.pyc
./world/refer.py
./world/__init__.py
./hello.py
./__init__.py
```

While I expect the `config` be there along with the YAML file it contains. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Why `graft`? Why not (in MANIFEST.ini) `include config/*`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example **setup.py** to contains the data file and ref to find that.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(...
      packages=find_packages(),
      package_data={'': ['config/*.yml'],
                    },
...)
```

[setup tools doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html)